# OnRectangleToolClick: How to identify the rectangle?

Tags: teechart

If I use the OnRectangleToolClick callback, can I get the properties/attributes of the rectangle that has been clicked/selected? i.e. can I get things like the text on the rectangle and color, transparency etc.?

I want to be able to display an editor (implemented in my code, not the standard tchart editor) where the user can edit the properties of the rectangle.

Along similar lines, I'd like to be able to identify the line that was selected or dragged when onDrawLinetoolDragging event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClick` event in `TRectangleTool` gives you the tool in the `Sender` parameter. So you can do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ChartTool1Click(Sender: TAnnotationTool; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Sender is TRectangleTool) then
     with (Sender as TRectangleTool) do
     begin
       AllowDrag:=True;
     end;
end;
```

Note the `TRectangleTool` inherits from `TAnnotationTool`.

---

Regarding the `TDrawLineTool`, the `Sender` parameter in the `OnDragLine` event is the `TDrawLineTool`, not a `TDrawLine` in the array of `TDrawLine`, so you have to get the `TDrawLine` below the cursor with the `Clicked` function. Ie:

```
procedure TForm1.ChartTool2DragLine(Sender: TObject);
var CursorPos: TPoint;
    ClickedLine: TDrawLine;
begin
  if (Sender is TDrawLineTool) then
     with (Sender as TDrawLineTool) do
     begin
       CursorPos:=Chart1.GetCursorPos;
       ClickedLine:=Clicked(CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y);
     end;

  if Assigned(ClickedLine) then
     ClickedLine.Pen.Color:=clRed;
end;
```